# как задать ширину текста в menu tkinter? Возможно ли это?

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне надо чтобы написание горячих клавишь было на одинаковом расстоянии от пунктов меню. Я пытался отрегулировать это расстояние банальными отступами, но не помогло так как, я думаю каждая буква в слове занимает разный объём и поэтому ровно не получилось. Так же я пытался задать wridth пункту меню а мне пишет что такой функции  wridth не находит. Подскажите как решить эту задачу.

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()

king=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=king)
#первый пункт меню
file = Menu(king,tearoff = 0)
file.add_command(label='New                    CTRL+N')
file.add_command(label='Open                  CTRL+O')
file.add_command(label='Save                    CTRL+S')
file.add_command(label='Save as')
file.add_separator()
file.add_command(label='Exit')
king.add_cascade(label="File",menu=file)

#второй пункт меню
edit = Menu(king,tearoff = 0)
edit.add_command(label='Cancel                     CTRL+Z')
edit.add_separator()
edit.add_command(label='Cope                       CTRL+C')
edit.add_command(label='Paste                       CTRL+V')
edit.add_command(label='Cut                          CTRL+X')
edit.add_command(label='Delete                      Del')
king.add_cascade(label="Edit",menu=edit)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `file.add_command(label='New', accelerator="Ctrl+N")`, см. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3485519/4752653

Comment: P.S. ни у какого элемента управления нет свойства "wridth", а вот "width" у некоторых есть.